# List Items on same line in drop down menu

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I have a drop down menu where I want some of the list items to be in one line.

See [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/w7a3N/2/)

You will notice that under `Tab One`, there are 9 rows. I want there to be three rows with three items in each row. How can this be done in CSS?

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <ul id="menu">
        <li><a href="#">Tab One</a>
            <ul style="width: 300%;">
                <li><a href="#">Column one</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Column one</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Column one</a></li>

                <li><a href="#">Column two</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Column two</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Column two</a></li>

                <li><a href="#">Column three</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Column three</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Column three</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Tab Two</a>
            <ul style="position: relative; left: -100%; width: 300%">
                <li><a href="#">Tab 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Tab 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Tab 2</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Tab Three</a>
            <ul style="position: relative; left: -200%; width: 300%">
                <li><a href="#">Tab 3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Tab 3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Tab 3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    font-family: arial;
    margin: 0px;
    padding-left: 40px;
    padding-right: 40px;    
}

#wrapper {
    text-align: center;
    height: auto;
    margin: auto;
    min-width: 500px;   
}

#wrap {
    display: inline;
}

ul {
    font-family: Arial, Verdana;
    font-size: 14px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

#menu > li {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    width: 33.3%;
}


li ul {
    display: none;
}

ul li a {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #ffffff;
    border-top: 1px solid #ffffff;
    padding: 5px 15px 5px 15px;
    background: #1e7c9a;
    margin-left: 1px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

ul li a:hover {
background: #3b3b3b;
}

li:hover ul {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
}

li:hover li {
    float: none;
    font-size: 14px;
}

li:hover a { 
    background: #3b3b3b;
}

li:hover li a:hover {
    background-color: black;
    opacity: .7;
}
```

Comment: It looks like you are trying to create 3 columns under "Tab One".  However, you need some extra markup to delineate which elements form each column.  Otherwise, CSS by itself won't work.  Try expanding what you will accept as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/w7a3N/5/

Remove `>` from `#menu > li {`  and set inner `<li>` to `<li style="width: 33%;">`

Not sure if the `style="width:33%;"` is absolutely necessary since it works in Firefox 20 without it, but just to be safe.

**UPDATE**

You asked for a version that only does multiple columns under the first tab.  Here you go:

http://jsfiddle.net/w7a3N/6/

Gave First tab an id like so `<ul id="tab1"` and then added this to CSS:

```
#tab1 li{
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    width: 33%;
}
```

Comment: He wants your rows to be the columns according to the way that they're named

Comment: I find changing the order of things in your markup to make the Css work to be pretty undesirable, but hey, maybe the asker is okay with that.

Comment: Thank you so much - works perfectly. I probably won't need the update - that's why I deleted the comment but I really appreciate it.

Comment: we can leave it there in case someone else on the internet needs to know how to do it.